# Retrieve Current User in Django Outside Template

Tags: python, django

Currently I have a form that was built using the form wizard, the form is processed using a separate script that I wrote.  I need to pass the current user (user currently logged in) to this script so that I can run an insert query to my database.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
class QuestionWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        import process_form
        userID = request.user.id
        result =  process_form.main(form_list,userID)

        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            #'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
            'data_return': result[0],
        })
```

I believe the form wizard done function only accepts two variables.

Comment: Can't you just pass it as a keyword argument?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: Well I am unable to pass the 'request' object to the class, so not sure how I would do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a lot simpler than I anticipated.  Inside of the done function I added the following:

```
user_id = self.request.user.id
```

And then passed the user_id into the process_form function.

Annoying that I overlooked it, but glad that I figured it out.